# Unable to redeem the Gold trial given with Xbox One, "you can’t acquire this item in your currently selected language" error

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

When trying to redeem my 14-day Gold trial included with the Xbox One (S) console I receive this error (I've tried the website `microsoft.com//redeem` as well):

> You can’t acquire this item in your currently selected language. Change your language region in Settings or go to microsoft.com//redeem.

The console has been purchased from a leading retailer in the country I reside in and "location" in the Xbox system setting matches as well, but "language" and "language region" have been set to English. I'm wary of changing the setting since [account funds don't move between regions](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/update-microsoft-account-country-region) and Microsoft doesn't directly tell which of the three settings (language, language region, location) you have to modify:

> How to change your country/region on Xbox One
>
> 1. Sign in to your Xbox One console.
> 2. Press the Xbox button to open the guide.
> 3. Select Settings.
> 4. Select System.
> 5. Select Language & location.
> 6. Select your new location from the list, and then select Restart now.

Comment: If you set the region to English just so you can set the language to English, try to install all the currently available updates for your Xbox. It took Microsoft 3 years to find out that people actually want to use their console in a language that's different from their region.

Comment: @Nolonar: Yes, I've only set the region to English to use the console in this language. I've however used the console for two weeks and all updates must have been installed, I did also verify just recently.

Comment: Did you try changing the region again, now that you're most up-to-date?

Comment: "language region" is a sub-setting of "language", I only have English-variants available.

Comment: @Nolonar: I was careful because I had funds on my account, but I eventually found content to reduce the value under 10€. I changed the language to match my location and was able to redeem the code on the console.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the "language" setting (System → Language & location) to my regional equivalent from English in order to be able to redeem the code on the console, while the [Microsoft's webpage](https://redeem.microsoft.com/) still returned the same error. I didn't lose the funds on my account, apparently only the "location" setting is affected.

As a downside the console was set to an unwanted language (I use all of my devices in English), but I was able to switch back without affecting the ongoing trials (Game Pass and Gold).

Comment: You can switch back without a problem.